# Removing an Extension in a filename in HDFS using shell script

Tags: unix, hdfs

Please help me how to remove an extension in a filename in HDFS using
 unix shell script.

For example, my initial filename is sample.txt.gz. I want to remove
 the .gz in the filename.

Here what I have done so far.

```
#Parameters 

baseDirHdfs=${1} dss=${2} ds=${3} processDirHdfs=${4} filename=${5} kerberosKeytab=${6} kerberosPrincipal=${7}

kinit -kt ${kerberosKeytab} ${kerberosPrincipal}

#Removing .gz extension 

newFilename=echo ${filename} | cut -f1-6 -d '.'

#Decompressing .GZ Files 

hdfs dfs -cat /${baseDirHdfs}/${dss}/${ds}/${processDirHdfs}/${filename}|gzip -d|hdfs dfs -put - /${baseDirHdfs}/${dss}/${ds}/${processDirHdfs}/${newFilename}
```

Comment: Please include what you have done so far.

Comment: Give an example with sample input and expected output.

Comment: Hi @WebArtisan, I have updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @MayankPorwal, I have updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: @CarlAmil expected output?

Comment: @MayankPorwal for example sample.txt.gz, the expected output is sample.txt I want to remove .gz 

P.S. this file is in HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the filename and extensions are separated by a `dot(.)`

So, something like this will do it:

```
mayankp@mayank: $file=myfile.sh
mayankp@mayank: $file_name=`echo $file| awk -F'.' '{print $1}'`
mayankp@mayank: $echo $file_name
myfile
```

Let me know if this helps.